# Finding every $\{a_n\}$ such that $\sqrt{a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}}\in\mathbb N, a_n=d_{n-1}d_n$ where $d_n=(a_n, a_{n+1})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Question** : Find every possible pair $(k,l,m)\in\mathbb Z$ such that the following $(1),(2)$ hold where 
>   $$a_0=a_1=1, a_{n+2}=ka_{n+1}+la_n+m\ (n\ge 0).$$
>
> $(1)$ $a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}\gt 0$ is a square number for any $n\ge 1$.
>
> $(2)$ $a_n=d_{n-1}d_n$ for any $n\ge 1$ where $d_n$ is the greatest common divisor of $a_n, a_{n+1}$.

**Motivation** : I was surprised to know $(k,l,m)=(6,-1,-2)$ satisfies the condition(see below).

$$a_n : 1\ \ 1\ \ 3\ \ 15\ \ 85\ \ 493\ \ 2871\ \ 16731\ \ 97513$$
$$d_n : \ 1\ \ 1\ \ \ 3\ \ \ 5\ \ \ 17\ \ \ \ 29\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 99\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 169\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

We can easily prove that the $(k,l,m)=(6,-1,-2)$ case satisfies the condition. Then, I've been interested in finding the other $(k,l,m)$, but I'm facing difficulty. How can we find every possible pair $(k,l,m)$?

One way is, of course, to use computer. Then, however, we'll still face difficulty for finding **every** possible pair. My question also includes whether we can get some necessary conditions which enable us to search only **finitely** many cases. Can anyone help?

Comment: At least $2$ families of such $(k,l,m)$ exist for research:
$$(k,l,m)=(0,~ -1,~ c^2), \quad c\in \mathbb{N}, c\ge 2;$$
$$(k,l,m)=(2c^2-2,~ -1,~ 2-c^2), \quad c\in \mathbb{N}, c\ge 2.$$